# Is it possible to style different CTabFolders in Eclipse E4 CSS styling?

Tags: css, eclipse, e4

I'm trying to identify if it is possible to style different *CTabFolder* in different *MPartStack* for Eclipse E4.

[Here is my example Application look and feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEliR.png)

Here is my CSS file:

```
.MPartStack {
   background-color: white; 
   color: black; padding: 0px 4px 5px;
}

CTabFolder {
   background-color: white;
   swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering');
   swt-selected-tab-fill: rgb(185, 185, 185);
   swt-outer-keyline-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
   swt-unselected-close-visible: true;
   swt-unselected-image-visible: true;
   swt-tab-outline: rgb(94, 94, 94);
}

CTabItem:selected { 
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: white; 
}

.MPart { background-color: white; }
```

As it can be seen on the example Application the PartStack on top does not have any tabs opened yet and it displays the grey background (which I would prefer to see a white background there).

I have tried using the **.empty** selector in the MPartStack like:

```
.MPartStack.empty {swt-selected-tab-fill: yellow;}
```

but was not able to make it work.

Is it possible to style the background of the empty CTabFolder?

Comment: I can't see anything simple. I think you would probably have to write your own custom tab renderer.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the reply. I have just started looking at the E4 CSS styling from the last couple of days. I was trying to style my application without the help of CSS Spy. I just used it and in fact the answer to my question might be simple enough. I will have a better look at the selectors through the ID to try to help out.

Comment: @greg-449 You're spot on. I would probably  need to write my own custom tab renderer. Thanks for the help